# Excel VBA - For/If to paste multiple examples which match Keyword into one cell, separated by commas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I'm working on producing an "Evidence Library" for my work. This consists of a workbook with two sheets: "Definitions" which includes column B for the term, Column C for definition, and Column D for Relevant Examples. Column D I am trying to populate with a VBA script for each specific term.

To do this I have tried to write a script which reads through the "Keywords" (Column I) column of my second sheet, "Evidence Library". When it finds a match for the keyword I am looking for, it copies a hyperlink to the evidence in question (in column B).

I've managed to write a basic script which achieves this to an extent. My issue is twofold: one, the script will overwrite the previous hyperlink examples when running through the loop and pasting, so only the last returned value will be displayed, and two: the keywords column has multiple entries and I'm unsure how to make the code realise that keywords within the cells for each entry are separated by a semicolon (";") - it only works when the keyword in question is the only one present within the cell.

I feel like I need to have the code store the hyperlinks in an array separated by commas and only paste at the end of the loop once they are all stored but I'm unsure how best to achieve this as I only have a very rudimentary understanding of coding.

For reference, this is what I currently have:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

a = Worksheets("Evidence Library").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To a

    If Worksheets("Evidence Library").Cells(i, 9).Value = "Keyword" Then

        Worksheets("Evidence Library").Cells(i, 2).Copy
        Worksheets("Definitions").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Evidence Library").Activate

    End If

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: A cell can only contain one hyperlink.

Comment: @Tim Williams I know that it's possible to have more than one hyperlink in a cell if pasted from Microsoft Word, by pasting it as an MS Word object - is there no way to achieve something similar using VBA?

Comment: That's just sitting *over* a cell and technically not really "in" Excel even - it's a whole word document embedded in the sheet.